# Measure the 'gain' of this circuit

Tags: transistors, amplifier, analog, gain

I made this schematic using NI Multisim and I got asked to find the ‘gain of this circuit using a 1V p-p 1kHz sine signal’ and I was unsure about this because I’m not sure if it means voltage gain or current gain. Anyways I put the desired signal in, but the waveform is the exact same as shown below and I don’t see some type of gain. I just need to know the gain of this circuit and whether this waveform is correct.

[image: Emitter follower]
[image: Oscilloscope]

Comment: The emitter-follower (input to base, output at emitter, collector tied to some source) will have a voltage gain very close to 1 (but just slightly less.) It definitely can provide added current compliance, though. (But I don't imagine the question was about that. You are in a better position to guess on that.)

Comment: *I'm not sure this and I'm not sure that* Well, educate yourself and be sure. Even if you have a **wrong** opinion then **I** would respect you more than when you have **no** opinion. So you think this circuit has to have gain, **why**? What type of circuit is it? A common...? And do those have voltage gain?